# Load CSV file into Database Table Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, csv, import

As said in my previous question I am having trouble loading data into my table through a csv file.  The error I am getting is that the file is not found but it's there.  Could this be a WAMP issue i.e. permissions? You can find the code below along with the error.

Appreciate your help as always:

```
function load_table() {
global $wpdb;
$filename = 'upper_db_.csv';
$table_nme = $wpdb->prefix . "upper_winds";
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $filename . "'
INTO TABLE $table_nme
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
"; 
$wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

**File 'c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\wp-test\upper_db_.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)**

P.S.  I have tried using backslashes, giving full path and I have also tried using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE but to no avail.

Comment: Update - Tried uploading it live onto a wordpress test domain and this time I get Access denied for use .... When I use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE I get file not found.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok found out where the problem lies.  Although I was escaping the " , the path \ was being truncated and thus the SQL command would not find the file. Whilst I have solved this locally, I now need to get the same result on the server.  Appreciate some ideas.  I had to /// to get the path working.

Answer (score 2):

Problem has been solved using the below

```
$filename = str_replace("//","//////",__DIR__ ."/file.csv");
```

The plugin has now been completed and can be viewed at http://howtoflyahelicopter.com/aviation-weather-briefing/